# Symfony2 cache bundle (Similar to Zend Cache)

Tags: symfony

Is there any Symfony2 cache bundle that is similar to Zend Cache? (I'm not talking about Symfony2 HTTP cache bundle).

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the cache bundles [here](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=cache).